# Safari "Add to home screen" App redirects to HTTPS but safari stays at HTTP

Tags: ios, ipad, redirect, ssl, safari

This is kind of weird!

I had a site running on HTTP. I opened it up on Safari(IOS 9.2) on Ipad and it loads fine. I added it to home screen and it works fine.

I installed SSL on the site and redirect all non-ssl traffic to SSL. I opened it up on Safari(HTTPS) and added to home screen. It works fine.

I removed the SSL(changed it back as it was). I opened it up on Safari, it works fine. I added it to home screen. It doesn't work anymore on the home screen app. It is trying to load HTTPS which doesn't exist anymore and show the page is not found error.

I tried to clear cache and website data, restarting ipad but none seem to work. It works perfectly on safari and desktop browsers but not when added to home screen. I tried it on another Ipad but this seems to be working fine there too!

Any idea what's causing this on this particular iPad?

I read that some HSTS header may cause it but the server is not using any. Also safari itself seems to be working fine.